# Console error when I run "build/nodes/runnodes"

Tags: corda

I am running Corda bootcamp-cordapp and do "./gradlew deployNodes" without any problems. But when I run "build / nodes / runnodes" they open the four console and show "Illegal variable name".

Comment: Please check the logs of the nodes under `build/nodes/PartyA/logs` (check also PartyB, PartyC and Notary).

Comment: Looks like your variable is illegal :/

Comment: I updated Gradle and went back to presenting the terminals. I installed XTerm too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to clone this repo https://github.com/corda/bootcamp-cordapp/blob/v4/build.gradle

and run `./gradlew deployNodes` and `./build/nodes/runnodes`

This repo is built to fast-fail any wrongfully configured cordapp development environment.

Unfortunately, we will not be able to help you with your issue with this much info.